# How to save the user registration date [rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I save an user through a registration, I want to save the day in which this registration is made. I've tried using `Date.today`, but it doesn't work.

What's the best solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Time.now` should work. Also, if your model has [timestamps](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) you could use the `created_at` attribute.

To convert a datetime to a date you can use `Time.now.to_date` or `created_at.to_date`. Depends on what you end up using.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend that you use [`devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).  You'll get `created_at` and `updated_at` fields built-in to a `user` model, which will automatically track the user registration date and most recent change date, respectively.

A single line in your `user` model will insert `devise`-based authentication and get you a lot of features with little or no programming effort on your part:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :recoverable
```